# How to implement Fluent Design (acrylic glass and reveal highlight) in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a WPF application and I would like to style it according to [Fluent Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/fluent-design-system). It seems that most aspects (responsive layout, navigation etc.) can be achieved using standard WPF mechanisms, however such features as acrylic effect and reveal highlight are quite difficult to implement in WPF.

I found certain solutions with SetWindowCompositionAttribute ([Adding the "Aero Glass" blur to your Windows 10 apps](https://www.withinrafael.com/2015/07/08/adding-the-aero-glass-blur-to-your-windows-10-apps/)), but this attribute is not documented and I'm not sure if this is the best solution. Additionally, if I understand things right, it doesn't allow me to control the acrylic color.

Is there a good way to implement fluent design in WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, standard WPF controls don't provide an "official" way to implement the acrylic and reveal highlight effects.

You can try using third-party libraries for this. For example [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/controls/wpf/) controls, which include both acrylic and reveal highlight features: [Fluent Design Support](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/401394/common-concepts/fluent-design-support).

The screenshot below illustrates what you can get:
[image: Fluent Design Example]

You can download this example at [How to Create a Unique Design for a WPF View using Appearance Options](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/How-to-Create-a-Unique-Design-for-a-WPF-View-using-Appearance-Options).

Another possible solution is to use the [FluentWPF](https://github.com/sourcechord/FluentWPF) package.